# Java Swing, can't see the error

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am at a very strange problem, I have a customized JPanel, which I want to draw a circle, but nothing happens ... here is my source, hope somebody sees the mistake, I can't find it.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CircleView extends JPanel {

public CircleView() {}

@Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(10, 10, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are testing the `CircleView`?

Comment: I am adding it to a layeredPane. I am able to add images to it, but as soon as I add the CircleView, nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that not true at all

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at KondorExport.Util.Helping.CustomComponent12.<init>(CustomComponent12.java:19)
        at KondorExport.Util.Helping.CustomComponent12$1.run(CustomComponent12.java:37)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - class CircleView is public, should be declared in a file named CircleView.java
        at KondorExport.Util.Helping.CircleView.<clinit>(CustomComponent12.java:44)
        ... 10 more
```

1) remove constructor

2) add `super.paintComponent(g);`

this one can run

```
class CircleView extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(100, 100);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int margin = 10;
        Dimension dim = getSize();
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawOval(margin, margin, dim.width - margin * 2, dim.height - margin * 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I read some howtos and I assumed, that what I wrote was enough, will try that ^^

Comment: seems as if, the class works fine. Adding it to the layeredPane is the problem ...

Answer (score 3):

It's because your component has no dimensions, hence why the sscce provided by [@mKorbel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053976/java-swing-cant-see-the-error/8054114#8054114) uses some "magic" dimensions when defining the component's preferred size.